# Filtrado de subsets con dos variables

Tags: pandas

Tengo el siguiente dataset

```
url = https://raw.githubusercontent.com/joanby/python-ml-course/master/datasets/customer-churn-model/Customer%20Churn%20Model.txt
```

¿Cómo puedo filtrar un subconjunto con a partir de dos variables? He estado utilizando el siguiente código pero me genera error:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv(url)
print(data[(data["Day Mins"]>300 and data["State"] == "NY")])
```

me genera un error de tipo

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

¿Cómo puedo hacer el filtrado del dataset con dos variables?

Comment: Utiliza los operadores Bitwise y no los booleanos, osea `&` en vez de `and`

Comment: @Christian lo hice pero me genero otro error de tipo TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: Verifica que la columna `Day Mins` sea de tipo entero (para pandas)

Comment: @Christian Ya encontre el error, cuando hacia esta linea `print(data[(data["Day Mins"]>300 and data["State"] == "NY")])` , no estaba cerrando el parentesis antes de and `print(data[(data["Day Mins"]>300) and (data["State"] == "NY")])`

Comment: No me había dsto cuenta, pero que bueno que hayas solucionado tu problema